# Maven: adding dependency not present in the mirror

Tags: maven

We are using a local nexus mirror for all of our dependencies.
I need the following dependency in one of the projects:

```
<depedency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</depedency>
```

from the repository: http://www.smartclient.com/maven2

But maven is giving me error saying that "Failure to find com.smartgwt:smartgwt:jar:3.0".
What might be the problem and how can I solve it?

(Maybe this is very trivial question but I am fairly new to Maven)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Nexus is working for all your standard dependencies hosted on Maven Central.

You can work out where Maven is downloading from by turning on debugging with the `-X` parameter when doing a build.  There will be a lot of noise but if you look a few lines above where your build fails because of failing to find the dependency, it will tell you:

- where it is trying to download the dependency
- whether it is using a mirror
- if there are any HTTP error codes when downloading

---

How is `http://www.smartclient.com/maven2` set up in your Nexus proxy?  As a separate proxy repository?  Can Nexus access this repo (is it 'In Service' and not blocked)?

---

Is this repository in Nexus added to the 'public' group?  If you don't want this then:

You have to configure a separate mirror in your settings.xml for this repository which points to the URL in Nexus.

Also check that you have added the repository in your POM, e.g.

```
<project>
...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>smartclient</id>
            <name>SmartClient Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
...
</project>
```

And then configure a proxy entry in your settings.xml for this repository:

```
<settings>
...
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>smartclient-nexus-proxy</id>
            <mirrorOf>smartclient</mirrorOf>
            <url><url of your smartclient proxy repository in Nexus></url>
        </mirror>
    ...
```